# Undefined form variable when rendering a partial in rails after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have been trying for a while to implement a dynamic dependent form using AJAX in rails 4.0.  I have a `bike` model which `has_one` `make` and `model`.  It also `has_many` `quotes`.  The goal is to have the second form's collection field (`model`) populate after the first field `make` is selected.

The form loads correctly and the AJAX call once the first field is selected is made and returns the appropriate set of data (confirmed via puts in the console).  However, I am unable to figure out how to then render the partial appropriately.  I am getting the error below.  I understand there is no f variable once the partial is rendered via the AJAX call but how do I go about designing the form without the f variable?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007f95b0fc2068>:0x007f95b54e2490>):
    1: <%= f.label :name, 'Model' %>
    2: <% if !current_models.blank? %>
    3:  <%= f.collection_select :name, current_models.collect{ |m| [m.name,m.id]}, :id , :name, include_blank: true %>
    4: <% else %>
  app/views/shared/_model_questions_fields.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__model_questions_fields_html_erb__894239665582553972_70140482609500'
  app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:70:in `update_model_select'
```

quotes/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :bikes do |builder| %>
            <p><%= render 'shared/bike_questions_fields', :f => builder %></p>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Show Quote", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

'shared/bike_questions_fields'

```
<%= f.fields_for :makes do |builder| %>
    <p><%= render 'shared/make_questions_fields', :f => builder %></p>
<% end %>

<%= f.fields_for :models do |builder| %>
    <div id="bikeModels"
        <p><%= render 'shared/model_questions_fields', :f => builder, :current_models => [] %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

'shared/model_questions_fields'

```
<%= f.label :name, 'Model' %>
<% if !current_models.blank? %>
    <%= f.collection_select :name, current_models.collect{ |m| [m.name,m.id]}, :id , :name, include_blank: true %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.collection_select :name, [], :id , :name, include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

in quotes controller:

```
def update_model_select
    models = Model.where(:make_id=>params[:id]).order(:name) unless params[:id].blank?
    render :partial => "shared/model_questions_fields", :locals => { :current_models => models }
end
```

in quotes.js.coffee:

```
ready = ->
  jQuery ($) ->

  # when the #make field changes
  $("#quote_bikes_makes_name").change ->

    # make a POST call and replace the content
    make = $("select#quote_bikes_makes_name :selected").val()
    make = "0"  if make is ""
    jQuery.get "/quotes/update_model_select/" + make, (data) ->
      $("#bikeModels").html data

    false


$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Comment: Change `<p><%= render 'shared/bike_questions_fields', :f => builder %></p>` to `<p><%= render 'shared/bike_questions_fields', locals: { f: builder } %></p>` ?

Comment: That line of the code is not the origin of the error.  The error happens when the `render partial` code in the controller is executed via the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing `'shared/model_questions_fields'` to:

```
<%= form_for('quote', remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :bikes do |g| %>
        <%= g.fields_for :models do |i| %>
            <%= i.label :name, 'Model' %>
            <% if !current_models.blank? %>
                <%= i.collection_select :name, current_models, :id , :name, include_blank: true %>
            <% else %>
                <%= i.collection_select :name, [], :id , :name, include_blank: true %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```